# masstransit publish with context

Tags: c#, .net, publish, masstransit

How to pass custom value to MessageId when publish message ?

My topic endpoint configuration

```
cfg.Message<OrderSubmitted>(configTopology =>
{
     configTopology.SetEntityName("my-topic");

});
```

Somewhere in service I publish message like this

```
await azureServiceBus.Publish<OrderSubmitted>(contract);
```

How I can provide custom MessageId while publishing ? (I need this because I want to use ASB duplicate message detection)

I looked into source code of MassTransit and it seems like there is an overload method where I can pass `IPipe<PublishContext<T>> publishPipe` as 2nd parameter but I don't understand but question is how to create this object properly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set any of the envelope properties and message headers by specifying a callback with `Send` or `Publish`.

```cs
await bus.Publish<OrderSubmitted>(message, x =>
{
    x.MessageId = someGuid;
});
```